# How to create multiple discord bot statuses with Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord.js

I want to add something so after it plays the block from the API, I want it to be playing another status.  For example, if it plays the block for some mins then it changes to playing something like "hello world", then it changes back to playing block after few mins.  Below is the code I currently have:

```
function updateBlock() {
    let response3 = axios.get(`https://google/api/getblockcount`)
    .then((response3) => {
        return Promise.resolve(response3);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Can not connect to API");
        console.log(error);
        return Promise.resolve({
            failed: true
        })
    });

    response3.then((response3)=> {
        if (response3.failed) {
            console.log("API Response Failed");
            return response3;
        }
        let b = response3.data;
        try {
            Client.user.setActivity("B: " + b, { type: 'WATCHING' })
            .then()
            .catch(console.error);
        } catch(err) {
            console.log("This is an API error catch");
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}

Client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(botName + " online!");
    updateBlock();
    setInterval(() => {
        updateBlock();
    }, 10000);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you are using discord.js library, this is how to display a random item from array `textList` in which is also block height received from API, changing every 1min.

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    setInterval(async ()=>{
        let {data: blocks} = await axios.get('https://chain.ragnaproject.io/api/getblockcount').catch(console.log)
        let textList = ['Hello World','Lorem Ipsum','Discord Bots', 'Blocks: ' + blocks]
        var text = textList[Math.floor(Math.random() * textList.length)];
        client.user.setActivity(text , { type: 'WATCHING' })
    },60000) // milliseconds
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out really appreciate

Comment: It won't boot up, I tried editing too     },60000); // milliseconds

Comment: Can't be, I tested that code using my own bot. Is there any error in console?

Comment: Did you change it on both places `client.on..` and `client.user.setActivity...`?

Comment: Thanks it working great , really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [`Client.user.setActivity()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity): the first argument is the name of the game you want to display, the second is the `options` object. `options.type` defines the string that comes before the name of your game: "Playing", "Watching", "Listening to" and "Streaming". The [`ActivityType`s](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ActivityType) are respectively:

```
'PLAYING'
'WATCHING'
'LISTENING'
'STREAMING'
```

If you set `'STREAMING'` as type, you can also set `options.url` to be the URL of your livestream.
Here's a sample implementation:

```
client.user.setActivity("your sample text", {
  type: 'WATCHING'
});
// OR
client.user.setActivity("Overwatch", {
  type: 'STREAMING',
  url: "https://example.com"
});
```